# Add progressbar when inserting records in database

Tags: .net, vb.net, progress-bar

I got an assignment to implement a progress bar while records are inserting.
And I don't know where to start.

To be more clearly, I'm working on a program which needs to read all the text in a text file. And needs to split these txt files. Next it needs to be inserted into a database.

Now my boss wants to have a progressbar while the records are inserting so he could see how far the insert is completed.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: first get all your data and split all the data. Count the number of items to insert then just insert and increment by one until reach the total amount and use: `CurrentItemCount / TotalItemCount * 100` to get percentage.

Comment: What did you try so far? I don't see any code. This makes it hard to help you.

Comment: @muffi I don't know where to start I have added a Toolstrip to my form but that's it, I'm sorry...

Comment: Try what i told you. but if your expecting us to code it for you it won't happen here.

Comment: @Mederic I didn't say that someone needed to code it for me.

Comment: So try what I told you.

Comment: Then try using the ProgressBar. You will find this control in "Common Controls". There are so many ways to use this control, it is very simple and will do what you want.

Comment: The ProgressBar isnt a magic spell - it can only report the progress that **you** measure in code.  Considering the vague description provided, it sounds like you'd have to slow the process down in order to report actual progress.  Might be better to speed it up and simply show the Marquee style meter to appease the boss.

Answer (score 0):

Set progress bar's maximum value at start of code

```
ProgressBar.Maximum = TotalItemCount
```

Then all you have to do is add one every time you insert a record.

```
'Add this bit of code after you inserted one record
ProgressBar.Increment(1)
```

Comment: Just a little heads up: `Refresh()` forces a synchronous redraw and **does not** need to be called to see the changes. If this process is done properly using multithreading and marshalling calls to the UI, then calling `Refresh()` is unnecessary and will only result in the UI thread being potentially blocked and in the progress bar being redrawn twice.

Comment: Calling `PerformStep()`, `Increment()` or modifying the `Value` property will result in the progress bar redrawing itself.

Comment: ah okay. I will remove it from answer as not needed. Thanks for the heads up